# How to run a flutter app with iOS theme (look & feel, behavior)

Tags: flutter

I needed to see **how my UI would look on an iOS device**, while working with **only** android emulator. *(a common case for Linux/Windows developers)*

Wanted a switch I could set just for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `platform` property in the app's `theme` did the trick.
The important line: `platform: TargetPlatform.iOS`

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'app,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS, //Makes the UI look and feel like iOS 
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'app'),
)
```